# Justification for Dummy Variable When Cook's < 1

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, cooks-distance

For a class project, I have a data set of restaurants and health inspection scores.  I want to indicate if a restaurant was closed or not due to violations as this seems to be a significant predictor of price in one model and popularity in another.  However with the current predictors, all of my values for Cook's Distance are < 0.09.  I already have the mean and latest inspection scores as significant predictors (p-value < 0.05).  A low enough inspection score already implies they were closed.  Can I justify adding a dummy variable, 1 or 0, closed/not-closed, without over-fitting the model?